# Sniff iphone network packets?

Tags: iphone, packets

How to capture iphone network packets ?
im using windows 
is it possible to capture its packets through wifi ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org)

You can set this up as a proxy server, and then set the proxy on your iPhone to this.  You should be able to see all the traffic, included encrypted traffic.  This is the program used to determine that Path was downloading the entire Contacts database for its users.

Comment: This is brilliant - It can even intercept SSL traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WireShark or Cain & Abel.  You would connect your phone to wifi and sniff the packets based on it's IP.

Comment: My vote also goes for WireShark.

Comment: My vote is for [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), it has a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this with OS X is to set up an ad-hoc wifi network on my Mac, connect the phone to it and share my wired connection with the ad-hoc wifi network. Then I can capture on the wifi card's interface and see traffic going to the iPhone. Presumably you can do a similar thing with Windows.

Comment: how is it going with windows ?

Comment: A quick google for "windows create adhoc wifi" yields some results which will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Paros](http://www.parosproxy.org/index.shtml) to set a proxy on your computer and route your iPhone through that proxy. Paros will then show you all the requests being made through the proxy from you iPhone. There is a Step-By-Step guide here: [Sniff your iPhones network traffic with Paros](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/06/sniff-your-iphones-network-traffic/).

I was searching for the same thing and came across these similar questions:

1. [How to show iphone apps sniffing HTTP Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750795/how-to-show-iphone-apps-sniffing-http-requests)
2. [iPhone and WireShark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598407/iphone-and-wireshark)

The second link shows the Paros solution.