# Different REST clients = different responses

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, rest, rest-client

I'm building an iPhone app that uses REST to talk to the server.

A couple of the APIs were getting a valid but incorrect response so I spoke to the server dev and he said they were working for him.

I downloaded RESTed from the Mac App Store and checked it on there and it got the same incorrect response.

The server dev checked again but insisted it was working.

I downloaded WizTools RESTClient and tried it on there and that worked and got the correct response!?

I'm lost for what to do now as I have never seen or heard of this before.

Can anyone provide any hints/tips of where to go from here?

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more detail than that to get anything but down-votes.

Answer (score 1):

Gah!

I found the problem.  I wasn't setting the Content-Type of the request to application/json.

Once that was set it worked with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

[Capture the requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598407/iphone-and-wireshark) sent using the two diffent client libraries, compare them and find out what is different.

From there you should be able to determine what is causing the different results, but if not, update your question with the two captures and we can analyse it further.