# View get requests being made by an iOS app

Tags: ios, post

Is there any way to view the get/post requests being made by an app from a users perspective?
I figure I won't have to worry about cross site request forgery if there isn't any way to view the requests going back and forth from my ios app to the server and it could potentially save me a lot of work. But at the same time I don't want to sacrifice security.

If there is a way to view the requests. How would you do it? Can I hook up a sniffer to my iPhone or something? If this isn't too difficult I would be interested in playing around with a couple of other apps (bwahahahaha)...

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598407/iphone-and-wireshark

Answer (score 0):

I use Charles for this purpose. http://www.charlesproxy.com/

You set it up on your computer and then set your iOS device to use it as a proxy. It will show you all network traffic and is easy to use. You can also pass back different information if you want to simulate a server that isn't running yet.