# iOS remote virtual interface does not work

Tags: ios, networking, capture, packet

I want to capture the net traffic on my iPhone. So I followed the guid on the official site.

1. Connect iOS device to the Mac via USB.
2. $ rvictl -s UDID

   I saw the interface rvi0 via ifconfig -l. I used tcpdump to capture the packet:
   $ sudo tcpdump -i rvi0 -n
   tcpdump: WARNING: rvi0: That device doesn't support promiscuous mode
   (BIOCPROMISC: Operation not supported on socket)
   tcpdump: WARNING: rvi0: no IPv4 address assigned
   tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
   listening on rvi0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes

   Then I used my iphone5(ios:7.0.2) browse a web page, which worked as normal. But there is 
   no pakect captured by the tcpdump.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the [Remote Virtual Interface docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECRVI). `rvictl -s <<UDID>>` just runs the tool with your device. An output line should read something like `Starting device <<UDID>> [SUCCEEDED] with interface <<INTERFACE>>`To view the packets, enter `sudo tcpdump -i <<INTERFACE>> -w trace.pcap`
When finished with your capture, remove the `RVI` using `rvictl -x <<UDID>>` and open `trace.pcap` (located in your current working directory) using a packet analyzer tool (i.e. WireShark, Cocoa Packet Analyzer, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

If the phone is ios7, you need to run Xcode 5. And preferably OSX 10.9 for best results.